# How to use legacy COM component from metro app

Tags: windows-runtime

I'm getting hard time to use COM objects in a metro app. As stated in MSDN the rules are:

1. Only registration free COM objects can be used
2. The COM can use only those APIs which are allowed for metro apps.

But my CoCreateInstanceFromApp always returns REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG. In desktop applications an error is written into the event log that SideBySide execution fails. But in metro application no such error is written into the event log.

I can use the same COM object from a desktop application as registration free over the similar manifest file.

Am I missing something? Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Does your COM object pass the app certification?

Comment: Have you includes your COM DLL in the app package?  Also take a look at this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/1dfb6dad-ccef-4f69-bd01-76b128c2ee4c/how-to-call-com-inetrface-in-metro-app