# Is it possible to use COM components in WinRT apps?

Tags: windows-runtime, unmanaged

Is it possible to use COM components in WinRT (Windows 8) apps?

Comment: What kind of COM components are we talking here? Custom registered system components, no, unregistered components included in the app itself, yes.

Comment: The latter... it's an unregistered third-party component that's going to be shipped with the app

Comment: It is *very* unlikely that an arbitrary 3rd party COM component will pass the Store test.  Which checks that code uses only winapi calls from the allowed subset.  A *very* small subset.  Run WACK.

Comment: related: [How to use legacy COM component from metro app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11281246/269126)